# BIP38 on multisig? Does it work?

Tags: private-key, multi-signature, bip38

I was making a multisig account with 3 of my Bitcoin addresses. The multisig account needs 2 of 3 private key to spend the Bitcoins in there. Then, I came up with an idea that nobody on the internet (at least, nobody on the first page on google) had tried or thought about.

Can I use BIP38 encryption on the private keys (in multisig)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use BIP38 with multisig.

It's not exactly a brand new idea, though. I've spoken with some people from Gem (https://gem.co/), that's exactly what their API lets you do.

Comment: Thanks man. You maked me thinking twice and now I understand it :D